# How do I reduce the flicker in IE on postback?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

IE causes a very unattractive flash or flicker when the page posts back. Without using an UpdatePanel, how can I reduce or remove it?

Most solutions suggest using page transitions like so:

```
<meta content="BlendTrans(Duration=0.1)" http-equiv="Page-Exit" />
```

We have been using this with success for a couple of years, but it's broken in IE8 Beta 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. It works in IE6, 7, and 8b2.

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="Alpha(opacity=100)" />
```

That will stop the flickering.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the same problem, but I have always used this solution, and it works across browsers:

```
<!-- Fixes the "Flash of Unstyled Content" problem (info here: http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp) -->
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```